# List extra-vars provided to the playbook

Tags: ansible

I have following scaled down version of playbook and I need to find out the list of `extra-vars` passed to this playbook. This is needed because sometimes user by typing mistake provide incorrect name of the `extravar` and the playbook will not use misspelled variable. SO I need to make sure user provide correct name of the extravar`.

```
---

- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    restart: 'on'
  tasks:

   - name: "WHEN CONDITION CHECK"
     shell: echo reboot
     when: "'off' in restart "
```

Example:

```
#This should run
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e restart=off
#This should get detected, like some extra var is passed. 
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e restarttt=off
```

Note: I already know `restart is not defined` check, I am trying to find the list of vars. As I want to use defaults also, So cannot use not defined check.

I am expecting to print following as output:

```
restart
restarttt
```

Comment: Have you considered using [`vars_promt`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_prompts.html) ? They will let you define values interactivelly, set defaults, and can be bypassed if you set the corresponding variable.

Comment: If you want to use defaults, won't it be good to use ```default``` jinja filter? Like {{ restart | default('off') }}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may leverage `/proc/<process-pid>/cmdline` file to read the command line arguments passed to the ansible playbook.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  tasks: 
  - name: "Get the command line args"
    shell: "cat -A /proc/{{ lookup('pipe', 'echo $PPID') }}/cmdline |sed -r 's/\\^@/ /g'"
    register: cmd_line
    delegate_to: localhost

  - name: "Print the arguments passed to the playbook"
    debug:
      msg: "{{ cmd_line.stdout.split(' ')|select() }}"
```

Example:

```
ansible-playbook foo.yml  -i inventory.yml  -e foo=123 -e 'bar=0 zoo=1'

PLAY [localhost] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Get the command line args] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [127.0.0.1 -> localhost]

TASK [Print the arguments passed to the playbook] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": [
        "/usr/bin/python3",
        "/home/p/.local/bin/ansible-playbook",
        "foo.yml",
        "-i",
        "inventory.yml",
        "-e",
        "foo=123",
        "-e",
        "bar=0",
        "zoo=1"
    ]
}
```

Once you have the list of args passed to the `ansible-playbook` you may write whatever logic is needed.

**Note**: the file `/proc/<pid>/cmdline` is having null separated list of arguments; you might want to write a better parsing logic if your code break at any point.

Answer (score 0):

If you run below code

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: True

  tasks:

    - name: host
      debug: var=vars
```

You will find your extra vars in the JSON structure, but it seems that it goes to the 'root' of the tree and to `hostvars` 'branch'

Hope it helps.